# Classic Game "Circle the Cat" algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Hi I was playing this game "Circle the Cat"
http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/chatnoir/chatnoir.html

I was wondering what algorithm makes the cat "intelligent"? How does the cat decide which direction to take?

One solution that comes to my mind is breadth first search and go in the direction with the shortest exit path.

I'm just inquisitive here. :-)

Comment: I think it just uses breath first search nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is just using [Djikstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (or equivalent) which is <del>an unweighted</del> single-source shortest-path algorithm that is quite good at solving this particular problem.

The cat is easily trappable by playing a few spots ahead -- the "intelligence" is easy to fool :) The cat doesn't seem to account for non-blocking tiles played ahead of it in a *potential* path, which makes me believe it's just a simple unweighted distance calculation.

When the cat becomes trapped it seems to pick a random direction, which might happen on a tie as well.

The cat could *possibly* be made "smarter" by adding a weight to certain tiles (such as those adjacent to blocking tiles).

Happy coding.

Comment: First of all, Dijkstra's is not an unweighted shortest path algorithm, it says so right there in your link. Second, you do not need either Dijkstra or A*, because this problem reduces to an unweighted graph problem. Not really relevant, but interesting: as long as the cat is at most 4 moves away from the exit, you are never able to trap it if you play right. Anything more (which is the case of the linked game) and you can always win, no matter what the cat does. This is why you think you beat the "intelligence" - in fact, it fooled you the first few times, since you can always win.

Answer (score 0):

I made a decent cat once, which used the minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning and iterative deepening.
I later made a LinkedIn Learning course describing that cat: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/ai-algorithms-for-gaming