# What's an algorithm to gauge how tough a Circle the Cat configuration is?

Tags: algorithm

Circle the Cat's a classic game in which the player tries to surround an escaping cat:
http://llerrah.com/cattrap.htm

How would one write an algorithm to evaluate how tough a certain initial configuration is? Or if the initial configuration is even possible to win if the cat is really smart?

I've tried using backtracking over the configurations of the game, but the number of configurations seems exponential. I've also tried using minimax with pruning to determine if games are even possible to win, but had a tough time determining how to define an optimal configuration for the algorithm - it's not just distance that matters.

I suppose the task becomes easier if we assume that the cat is performing BFS, since the cat will always veer towards the nearest exit, but even then, it's tough to define heuristics to determine how much the player is winning by.

Comment: I enjoyed the game,THANKS. Also,it seems that the construction of square of length equal to 2/3 node helps. I adopted the strategy from the center and won the game... Means,after fixing the square boundary,do recursive inner nodes(nodes which join boundary nodes) visit and backtracking! Someone better will surely produce positive result!

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641388/classic-game-circle-the-cat-algorithm

Comment: Interesting … the cat can always escape if he's at most 4 away? Otherwise, even if no blocks in the way, you can always block the cat? I wonder how to prove that … Also, @shekharsuman how are you defining your subproblems for recursion? Which inner nodes do you use?

Comment: @JohnHoffman-I won the game through playing manually,NOT USING THE CODE. It'll take me a long time to devise a solution for it!